# Inequality about Lebesgue Integral

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading the textbook on real analysis and came across the following inequality:

$\bar{\int}_Af+\underline{\int}_Ag\geq\underline{\int}_A(f+g)$ whenever $|\underline{\int}_Ag|<\infty$

where we **define**:

$\bar{\int}_Af\triangleq\inf\{\int_Ah|h\geq f\text{ is elementary}\}$

$\underline{\int}_Af\triangleq\sup\{\int_Ah|h\leq f\text{ is elementary}\}$

I can prove it when $\bar{\int}_Af>-\infty$, but could anyone give me some hint how to prove it when $\bar{\int}_Af=-\infty$? In this case, we have $\bar{\int}_Af+\underline{\int}_Ag=-\infty$ and what's remaining is to show that: $\underline{\int}_A(f+g)=-\infty$. Intuitively, this must be true, but I am wondering how to prove it. Simply put, my question is how to prove:

$\underline{\int}_A(f+g)=-\infty$ whenever $\bar{\int}_Af=\underline{\int}_Af=-\infty$ and $|\underline{\int}_Ag|<\infty$.

---

**Proof** for the case with $\bar{\int}_Af>-\infty$:

If $\bar{\int}_Af=\infty$ this is trivial, so we assume $|\bar{\int}_Af|<\infty$. In this case, we have:

$|\bar{\int}_Af|=|\bar{\int}_Af^+-\underline{\int}_Af^-|
=|\bar{\int}_A(-f)^--\underline{\int}_A(-f)^+|
=|-\underline{\int}_A(-f)|<\infty$

Suppose otherwise, i.e.:

$\bar{\int}_Af+\underline{\int}_Ag<\underline{\int}_A(f+g)$

then since $|\bar{\int}_Af|<\infty$, we can move term as:

$\underline{\int}_Ag<\underline{\int}_A(f+g)-\bar{\int}_Af
=\underline{\int}_A(f+g)+\underline{\int}_A(-f)$.

Now since $|\underline{\int}_A(-f)|<\infty$ and $|\underline{\int}_Ag|<\infty$, we can find two finite numbers: $u<\underline{\int}_A(f+g)$ and $v<\underline{\int}_A(-f)$ such that $\underline{\int}_Ag \leq u+v$. By the definition of $\underline{\int}_A$, we can find elementary functions: $H,F$ such that:

$H\leq f+g$ and $u<\int_AH<\underline{\int}_A(f+g)$

$F\leq-f$ and $v<\int_AF<\underline{\int}_A(-f)$

Now at least the later function $F$ is integrable ($|\int_AF|<\infty$), so the integrals of two elementary functions are additive. By the additivity, the definition of $\underline{\int}_A$, and $H+F\leq g$, we have:

$\underline{\int}_Ag\leq u+v<\int_AH+\int_AF=\int_A(H+F)\leq\underline{\int}_A g$,

a contradiction.

Comment: Please include your proof for the case $\bar\int_A f\gt-\infty$. Also, what is $\bar\int_A$?

Comment: $\bar{\int}_Af$ and $\underline{\int}_Ag$ are not standard notations in Measure Theory.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have completed the notations and added my partial proof.